# How can I straighten out my dishwasher?

Tags: dishwasher

My dishwasher was open, and my eight year old accidentally tripped and landed on the door. Ever since then, when the door is open, it is angled slightly downwards instead of being straight. Otherwise, everything seems fine with it. If I had to guess, I'd suspect the door itself is fine but the dishwasher is no longer mounted as securely as before--it seems to have a bit of play in it when I wiggle. I'm not sure how to diagnose further, but I'd love to get it straightened out again.

Answer (score 3):

Usually they are fasted to your cabinet at two screw tabs along the upper front edge of the dishwasher. Open the door and look along there, as your first step would be to check/remove the mounting screws.

[image]

It is likely that the mounting tabs have been bent, causing the unit to sit in a non-level position. It's important that you get it back level or it may not operate properly and could leak. Once you remove the screws you should be able to *carefully* pull the unit out a bit to straighten the tabs.

There is a chance that you may also be fighting copper water supply tubing that has been distorted/bent/kinked when the unit moved. If this is the case, you will need to shut off and disconnect the water supply, power, and drain lines and pull the entire unit out to inspect and repair as needed.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that the bottom of the unit simply slipped rearward. Try pulling it forward. It should slide easily. You may need to remove the kick panel to get a grip on it. If that's the problem, try screwing the adjustable front feet down a bit to snug things back up.

If that's not the case, check for damage to the door near where the hinges attach. There may be deformation of the sheet metal.